# RESTFUL API : new Iron Router version this.request.body not working anymore

Tags: iron-router

I had my API fully functional and everything was working like a charm but with the last updates of Iron Router (Meteor update could impact?) my command

this.request.body

doesn't render nothing when I have a POST call on my API (all calls work good and I have no problem with GET this.params), I took a look at the docs and I don't see nothing talking about this, does anyone have an idea?

Thanks for your help =)

PS : I tried to replace it (without success obviously) by :
this.params.query.body
this.request.query.body
When I try to do a JSON.stringify on this.request it is empty so I guess it has been moved somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As asked here https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/1003, just add:

`Router.onBeforeAction(Iron.Router.bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))`

in your Meteor.startup